# windows service from C# working in local but not in distant desktop

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, virtual-machine

I am currently working on visual studio C# to make a windows service.

**I exported the project as "Release" "Any Core"** and tried it on my computer, and it **worked fine** using :

- sc create myService binPath= C:/myDocs/theService.exe
- net start myService

**I then copied it to my virtual machine** (itself on a server that I connect to using distant desktop)

when doing the same commands on the virtual machine it tells me

```
the service is not responding to the control function
error code 2186
```

when opening the services maintenance window and manually starting it I get

```
the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
error code 1053
```

**The two errors are different, but what's crazy is that it works on my computer just fine...**

**What I've tested / checked:**

- the .net version of the project and the vm are both 4.7
- I have added some try catch writing to a log file in the constructor and OnStart functions, but nothing is outputed.
- the service is ran as "localUser" on the vm with all rights, like on my computer
- I tried restarting the vm a couple times

Comment: don't waste your time, after 5 hours I've finally found out that it was because of the file name :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying to open a file at a location that do not exist apparently do weard stuff on windows :

- no exception catch
- service stop responding
- service returned error is strange

the error come from here:

```
string path = "C:/myDocs/myService.exe";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
    {
    }
}
```